# Do event listeners on Android get called in the same thread they are registered?

Tags: android, multithreading

As the title states, will event listeners on Android be called in the same thread they are registered? If the answer is yes, what happens if I register a listener in the run() method of a thread that then returns from run()? I presume the thread will terminate; then how will the event listeners get called?

Comment: No. Like any method, they are invoked on the thread they are *invoked from* (as opposed to *registered on*). For UI events this is the UI thread, thankfully. Callbacks are otherwise unrelated to threads or thread termination.

Comment: And if you think about it, that's really not possible. When the event occurs, how could the original thread possibly be commandeered?